# Selector element type 'char *' is not a valid object error

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to loop through an array of characters using a for-each loop, but when I do, I get an error:

```
+(NSDictionary*)charOccurance:(NSMutableArray *)inputCharacters
{
    if ([inputCharacters count] > 0) {
        for (char* currentChar in inputCharacters) { //this gives error

        }
    }
}
```

but if i change to `char *` to `id` I am able to loop through the array. Why can't I declare the element type as a character?

Comment: use `id` as the type temporarily, then in the body of the loop, `NSLog(@"%@", [currentChar class]);`.  That will tell you what type should be used instead of the `id` you just declared.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` do not hold primitive types, they hold `ObjectType`s. To do what you'd want, you would have to wrap your character in an `NSNumber` in order to build "an array of characters" in an `NSArray`.

Note I'm not saying this is the right thing to do. You'd be better using an `NSString` in this case.